# Disable weekends from WPF DatePicker, calender

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I have a simple datepicker in a wpf application. I want to remove all weekends from the calender when it's shown.
To achieve this I have used DatePicker's BlackoutDates property.

My code is as follows (MVVM architecture):

This is in XAML

```
<DatePicker Name="MyDatePicker">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CalendarOpened">
               <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.CalenderOpenedCmd,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" 
               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyDatePicker}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DatePicker>
```

Then in MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand CalenderOpenedCmd { get; set; }
CalenderOpenedCmd = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteMyDatePicker_RemoveSaturdays);
```

ExecuteMyDatePicker_RemoveSaturdays is the event.

```
private void ExecuteMyDatePicker_RemoveSaturdays(object obj)
{
    var datePicker = obj as DatePicker;
    if (datePicker == null)
        return;
    datePicker.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(1995, 1, 1);

    // In following 2 variables I'm deciding the range for BlackoutDates property.
    var minDate = datePicker.DisplayDateStart ?? DateTime.MinValue;  
    var maxDate = DateTime.Today;

   // In the following for loop, I'm checking every date in given range and if the day is Saturday or Sunday I'm adding them to blackoutdates to remove them form the calender.
    for (var day = minDate; day <= maxDate && DateTime.MaxValue > day; day = day.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            datePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(day));
        }
    }
}
```

The above code takes too much time for execution if the date range is 30-40 years wide. So I want to know either how to optimize this code or any other way to remove all the weekends form entire datepicker of WPF irrespective of what date range I provide.

Comment: Did you have a look inside its template? You could re-template it to do something *special* with dates when the date is visualized (i.e. detecting if it's saturday/sunday and e.g. hiding it).

Comment: That increases the time complexity of the code and makes it less interactive to use. As I'm displaying the entire calender, I'll have to check every day and hide if it's Sunday/Saturday which takes time.

Comment: How do you display *entire calendar*? 40 years is ~15000 days. If you mean time taken to show/hide individual dates in e.g. style trigger that it takes ms, you will not notice it. While you **do notice** time needed to create huge list of blackout dates on displaying calendar.

Comment: By entire calender I mean, I'm removing weekends form entire calender at once. For eg. if my calender is showing dates form 2000-1-1 to 2020-1-1, then I'm removing all weekends in that year span in one go. This process takes time.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it looks to me like you are removing the weekends every time that CalendarOpened is triggered. Maybe you can put that onto some initialize or load event instead.

Comment: You are also looping through every day in the range and checking to see if it is a Saturday or Sunday. You might try having a loop that locates the first Saturday in the range, add it to the blackout dates, and then loop by adding 7 to the day. By adding 7 you'll always know you are on a Saturday. Then do another loop for Sunday.